# Leaflet: Is there a way to use click event just like mouseout?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I made a map with leaflet by following the official Leaflet tutorial on [interactive choropleth maps](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html).

I would like to make the map compatible with smartphones, so I added a click event, which acts like hovering on a feature.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    click: highlightFeature
});
}
```

The consequence: When a user is clicking, the `hightlightFeatures` remain highlighted.

Is there a way to prevent this? In other words: Is there an event on the lines of `mouseout`, in order to activate `resetHighlight` by clicking another feature?

Answer (score 1):

The [highlightFeature](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) from the choropleth example can be changed to :

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
    geojson.setStyle(style); // This line will reset the style of all the features.
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}
```